# SQL query in apache calcite and teradata

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, teradata, apache-calcite

Need advise on apache calcite. We have some SQL queries running on Teradata. Now we want to run these sql queries (as it is) on Hadoop/Spark perhaps using Apache calcite.

We tried these SQL queries (as it is) in Spark SQL (2.6.3) and also in Apache calcite - but few queries dont run. The problem is if we define a derived variable (AS) and try to use it in the same query at same level, it does not WORK in SparkSQL and calcite but WORKS in Teradata. Example query:

```
select EMPNO, sum(deptno) as sum_dept, 
   case when sum_dept > 10 then 1 else 0 end as tmp 
from emps 
group by EMPNO; => WORKS in Teradata
```

But the same does not work in SparkSQL and Calcite. Throws following error:

> Error while executing SQL "select EMPNO, sum(deptno) as
>   sum_dept, case when sum_dept > 10 then 1 else 0 end as tmp from emps
>   group by EMPNO": From line 1, column 50 to line 1, column 57: Column
>   'SUM_DEPT' not found in any table (state=,code=0)

Does anybody (SparkSQL/Calcite expert) know if there is a way to make it work in sparkSQL or calcite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Standard SQL an alias can only be used in the ORDER BY clause, but Teradata allows it in any place. You must replace the alias with the original calculation:

```
select EMPNO, sum(deptno) as sum_dept, 
   case when sum(deptno) > 10 then 1 else 0 end as tmp 
from emps 
group by EMPNO;
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. Yes, sure this is one way to do it. In our case the alias is a complex one often containing multiple case statements. So wanted to know if there is easy way to do it. I think you are saying this is not possible?

Comment: The common way proposed by Standard SQL is nesting the query, i.e. assigning an alias in either a Derived Table or a Common Table Expression and then using it in the outer level.

Comment: Hi, I was looking for a tool to convert Teradata query into Hive/SQL query. I found one site "http://www.sqlines.com/online" that claims to do so. But for the above query it did not convert it correctly. I would love to hear if anybody has used any such tool with success. Desperately need this.

Comment: @sunillp did you have any success in finding such tool?